# smack jitsi-jingle examples

Tags: java, xmpp, voice, smack

I want to develop a project that can support voice chat, and I decide to use jitsi-jingle and smack, but I don't know where to start, are there any tutorials or little examples for me to learn jitsi-jingle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two examples at this link: [Click here](https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi)

One of them sending video and audio, the other one is receiving both of them. But there is no GUI. So how do you understand that it sends av? If your camera got control led on it, you can see turning it on. The other hand you can see how many bytes you sent and received at output.

You can run it with needed libraries.

Comment: the 2 examples are not using the jingle lib

Comment: Link is broken :(